# Separating content before and after the 1st equal sign

Tags: latex3

Is the following method the right one for separating content before and after the 1st equal sign?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn\getbefore:w#1=#2\q_stop{#1}
\cs_new:Npn\getafter:w#1=#2\q_stop{#2}

\NewDocumentCommand\beforeafter{m}{
    \getbefore:w#1\q_stop
    \par
    \getafter:w#1\q_stop
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\beforeafter{a=2+3}

\end{document}
```

P.S.: both parts will in fact be stored in token-list variables for further processing.

Comment: no need to scan twice if you are going to store anyway: just use your first definition modified to save #1 in one tl and #2 in another.

Comment: You're totally right.

Answer (score 3):

This approach does not use L3, but rather the `listofitems` parser.  Individual pieces of the most recent parsing can be obtained via `\gotten[1]`, `\gotten[2]`, etc.  The total number of pieces is accessible via `\listlen\gotten[]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar{=}
\newcommand\beforeafter[1]{%
  \readlist*\gotten{#1}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\gotten[]{%
    \ifnum\zcnt=1\else\par\fi
    $\z$%
  }
}
\begin{document}
\beforeafter{a=2+3}

With 3 pieces:

\beforeafter{a = 2+3 = z_1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll play with `l3` later in my code. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

This is a no nonsense method without reinventing the wheel:

```
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { = } { #1 }
\tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } }
\tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 } }
```

What in the case you have more than one `=` token?

You can split keeping spaces and restoring the `=` tokens afterwards:

```
\seq_set_split_keep_spaces:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { = } { #1 }
\seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \tl_trim_spaces:V \l_tmpa_tl }
\tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { = } }
\tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \tl_trim_spaces:V \l_tmpb_tl }
```

Spaces around the items at the left of the first `=` are trimmed and so those around the rest.